# Prove that if $|A \cup B|=|A \cap B|$, then $|A|=|B|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be sets. Prove that if $|A \cup B|=|A \cap B|$, then $|A|=|B|$

Comment: This seems like a silly question, because the stronger result $A=B$ holds (if the sets are finite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG let $|A| \le |B|.$ Then

$$|B| \le |A \cup B| = |A|+|B| - |A \cap B| \le 2|B|-|A \cap B|.$$

With $|A \cup B|=|A \cap B|$ this gives

$$|B|=|A \cup B|.$$

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$|A \cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$$

if $|A \cup B|=|A \cap B|$ then
$$|A \cap B|=\frac{|A|+|B|}{2}$$

Suppose $|A|>|B|$, then
$$|A \cap B|=\frac{|A|+|B|}{2}>|B|.$$

However, by definition, $A \cap B\subset B$.

Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is certainly false for the infinite case, take for example $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$ (the even numbers). But in the finite case it is true, as $A \cap B \subset A \cup B$ so if their cardinal is equal, then $|A\cup B|=|(A\cap B)\cup ((A\cup B)-(A\cap B))|$ and as this sets are finite and that union is disjoint, we have that $|A \cap B| = |A\cup B|=|(A\cap B)|+| (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)|$ which implies that $| (A\cup B)-(A\cap B)|=0$ and so that set is the empty set and every element of B is in the union an so in the intersection (by the emptyness) and therefore in A and similary every element of A is in the union and then in the intersection and therefore it is also in B. Deducing that both sets are equal